# create maven artifact out of generated GRPC code?

Tags: maven, grpc, grpc-java

I have a set of proto files - I want to generate the java code and package it as a maven module which I can distribute.

Currently I do it during the build of my project with `protobuf-maven-plugin` and `build-helper-maven-plugin`, but I have many apps in my system that uses these proto files to generate the java code so it seems like duplicate work. Mono repo not an option.

So I want to separately manage these proto files, generate the java code, and package is a maven artifact that all my other projects can import.

Not sure how to do that last part as in packaging the generated code as an artifact and publishing to internal place.

Answer (score 0):

In order to publish artifacts from a Maven Project, you need to do the following:

1. Set up repositories in the maven project containing proto files

   ```
   <distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>my-repo</id>
        <url>{link to internal maven repo snapshots}</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
    <repository>
        <id>my-repo</id>
        <url>{link to internal maven repo}</url>
    </repository>
   </distributionManagement>
   ```
2. Open *.m2/settings.xml* and add the repo id from step 1 here along with the credentials

   ```
   <servers>
    <server>
     <id>my-repo</id>
     <username>admin</username>
     <password>1234</password>
    </server>
   </servers>
   ```
3. Run the maven deploy command to publish artifacts to remote repositories

   ```
   mvn deploy
   ```

Please go through Maven docs [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-remote.html#:%7E:text=mvn%20deploy%3Adeploy%2Dfile%20%2D,%2DDversion%3D%20%5C)